# Android withText option does not work for action bar buttons on Huawei MediaPad (T1-A21L)

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

The buttons on the action bar on this tablet, if shown with text, suffer from text warping as in the screenshot below:

[image]

I tried many possible settings combinations (ifRoom, always, withText,...). Even attempting to manipulate the actual view of the button get me nowhere (or maybe I didn't persevere enough). Setting the widths of the TextView and the parent LinearLayout had no effect unless they're fixed numbers.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I neglected to mention that attempting to use an icon along with text *only* shows the icon. This is using the native action bar. Below is the xml of the action button above:

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/itemConfig"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
    android:title="Network Config"
    android:visible="true"/>
```

Setting the menu item in the following manner:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/itemConfig"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_networkconfig"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/network_config"
        android:visible="true"/>
```

causes this

[image]

So in essence, the tablet doesn't like text in its action bar. Any clues?

Comment: show toolbar code, menu xml

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: Post your design code.

Comment: Do you use `ActionBarCompat`, or the native `ActionBar` implementation? ([Just in case](http://www.xda-developers.com/the-sorry-state-of-android-fragmentation/).)

Comment: Sorry for the late response; please find the requested information above

Comment: I have seen this once with a cheap Chinese phone, somehow they broke the text wrapping algorithm system-wide (I guess it's because they never expected anyone to use the phone in English, so they "optimized" the algorithm for Chinese). I don't think there's really any good solution for this, unfortunately, short of manually rendering your own custom TextView.

Comment: That actually makes sense; if I have the time maybe I'll try that approach

Comment: Does it work on other devices? Which version of Android, both code compilation and what is running on this device?

Comment: What about using custom layout action item to solve the problem?

Comment: @JonAdams Yes it works on samsung and lenovo tablets, and even on a sony xperia smartphone. The huawei tablet is the only one that has this behavior among our test devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, it couldn't be done :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your menu code is correct. For reference check my menu item xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemConfig"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        app:showAsAction="withText|always"
        android:title="@string/network_config"/>
</menu>
```

Device will show text with icon only if we have space. You can check with landscape mode. Here is the example
[image: portarit mode]
[image: landscape mode]

Comment: Nice suggestion, but orientation has no effect in this case

Answer (score 1):

Source:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems

*If your menu item supplies both a title and an icon—with the title and icon attributes—then the action item shows only the icon by default.*

**If you want to display the text title, add "withText" to the showAsAction attribute.**

**Note:** *The "withText" value is a hint to the action bar that the text title should appear. **The action bar will show the title when possible, but might not if an icon is available and the action bar is constrained for space**.*

Comment: The fact that withText is only a hint is important to note of course. The case here is that the OS on Huawei decided that there's no space on a 7 inch tablet! My 5 inch smartphone shows both text and icon when asked!